# Non-resolvable parent POM for io.confluent:kafka-connect-storage

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am pretty new to Kafka and maven. I imported the code from the official repo of confluentinc (https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common) into eclipse as a maven project and I got the following error for all the projects. There is a Kafka docker is running in the same folder as the code. Any thoughts on how to solve this?
Is there a way to run this in the eclipse? what type of dependencies do I need to add?

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for io.confluent:kafka-connect-storage-         common-  parent:6.0.0-
SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer io.confluent:common:pom:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT from    ${confluent.maven.repo} was cached in
the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of confluent has elapsed or updates are
forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact io.confluent:common:pom:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT from/to confluent ($
{confluent.maven.repo}): Cannot access ${confluent.maven.repo} with type default using the available connector
factories: AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory, BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory and 'parent.relativePath' points at
wrong local POM'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responded to your Github issue.

SNAPSHOT builds will never be available from Maven Central and `${confluent.repo}` doesn't need changed.

Read the FAQ in the Github wiki. Clone and install each dependency (checking out the latest, stable (or necessary dependency version) branch and build/install each while skipping tests, if you would like).

Then that project should build.

Comment: Cant he just build a tagged version

Comment: @uh_big_mike_boi Ideally, yes. But sometimes people decide to fork repos for internal enterprise reasons

Comment: so if he just did like `git checkout 5.5.x` the maven command `mvn clean package` would work?

Comment: I guess what is a release tag, thats what I need to read up on

Comment: @uh_big_mike_boi That repo in particular is no longer tied to a Confluent Platform release, and now has versions like `11.0.x` for latest. But before that, the `-post` branches were used for releases and feature merging.

Comment: Oh because when I try to build kafka-rest, and I try  `git checkout 6.1.1-post` - which also is what https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest says, and just run `mvn package` I still get the error like the guy above.

Comment: Ah Im just going to download the whole confluent platform tar

Comment: @uh_big_mike_boi If you are looking for a specific connector that uses the `storage-common` library, then you can use `confluent-hub` https://www.confluent.io/hub/